# Theming Image fields in page.tpl.php

Tags: theming, media

I need to have have something like this:

```
<div class="gal-wrapper">
   <div class="gallery" id="r1"><img src="image01.jpg"></div>
   <div class="gallery" id="r2"><img src="image02.jpg"></div>
   <div class="gallery" id="r3"><img src="image03.jpg"></div>
   <div class="gallery" id="r4"><img src="image04.jpg"></div>....
</div>
```

My CCK Image field name is filed_image.
In page.tpl.php I have the following code:

```
<div class="gal-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ((array)$node->field_image as $item) { ?>
      <div id="" class="gallery"><?php print $item['view'] ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

So with this I am able to print all images form my Image Field.

**But I don't know how to dynamically change the value of id="r1", id="r2", id="r3" ....**

That value **must start from 1 and be auto increment**. For example  if I have 3 images the id should be id="1", id="2", id="3" or If there are 10 images I need id from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
<div class="gal-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ((array)$node->field_image as $item_id => $item) { ?>
      <div id="<?php print $item_id+1?>" class="gallery"><?php print $item['view'] ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **Thank you!**
Yes it is working! Problem solved :)